# Powershell - read multiple values from TSV text file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm creating a script that will monitor the status of one or more services running on one or more servers and will send out an email alert if ever one of them is stopped.  Admins will modify a single TSV text file, add their server name, and add one or more services they want to monitor on that server separated by commas.

TSV input file:

```
Hostname    Services
S-UTILITY   Actserv,AdobeARMservice
S-SCCM  RServer3,AdobeARMservice,VaultSvc
```

Code:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\services.txt -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach {
   $Service = $_.Services -split ','
   Get-Service -ComputerName $_.Hostname -Name $Service  | Select-Object | ft $_.Hostname, DisplayName,status -AutoSize
   }
```

This results in:

```
S-UTILITY DisplayName                   Status
--------- -----------                   ------
          Radmin Activation Server V1  Running
          Adobe Acrobat Update Service Running

S-SCCM DisplayName                      Status
------ -----------                      ------
       Adobe Acrobat Update Service    Running
       Radmin Server V3                Running
       Credential Manager              Stopped
```

This is fine so far.  However, what I don't know how to do is I would like to be able to handle each of the services listed for a given server individually within a variable.  As it is now, within the ForEach loop, the value for $Service returns all of the entered services for a server:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $Service

RServer3
AdobeARMservice
VaultSvc
```

...instead of just one at a time:

RServer3

In other words, I would like to run each listed service through the Get-Service command individually as I will later be using the variable to report on a specific service that is down on a specific server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe to another `ForEach-Object`.  If you need to keep the previous pipelined object, save it to a variable:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\services.txt -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach-Object {
    $Hostname = $_.Hostname;
    $Services = $_.Services -split ',';
    $Services | ForEach-Object {
        $Service = $_;
        Get-Service -ComputerName $Hostname -Name $Service  | Select-Object | ft $Hostname, DisplayName,status -AutoSize;
    }
}
```

Note that your output format is weird to me since you're creating a heading with `$Hostname` that doesn't contain anything, but if that's what you want that's fine.  Also `Select-Object` here is literally doing nothing.  You can remove it entirely and you'll be fine.

Comment: Oh, that is just perfect!  $Hostname returns the server and $Service returns an associated single service as desired.  I really don't need the table.  I was just using it as a way to see what information was stored in each variable.  I added a closing } and removed the Select-Object statement.  Works great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After further tweaking, I found this to be the final code I used allowing me to assign a variable for the server and each service name:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\servicecheck\services.txt -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $_.Hostname -Name ($_.Services -split ',') 
    } | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq "Stopped" } | ForEach-Object {
        $Server = $_.MachineName
        $DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
        }
```